# Image tag with strange behavior on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an old but simple html/css page with a barcode, that is generated by an ASP script. The problem is the barcode has different appearence on Internet Explorer and Chrome. The html/css code is very simple, still I can't understand what is going on. Already tried some modifications, without sucess. :(

For generating the bar code I have 2 gif images:

[image]

And the HTML/CSS is simple as this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img.barcode {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<tr>
    <td width="659" colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <img src="imagens/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/b.gif" class="barcode" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="imagens/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img

        ...

        src="imagens/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img
        src="imagens/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="imagens/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:3px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/b.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;"><img
        src="images/p.gif" class="barcode" style="width:1px;height:50px;">
    </td>
</tr>
```

In Internet Explorer it works perfecty:

[image]

But in Google Chrome I have this:

[image]

Please, anyone knows what is going on and how to solve?

Thanks!!

Comment: please update code include images

Comment: BTW why do you use `img`s anf not e.g. `span`s with background colors set in CSS? One improvement would be that the browser won't have to download two images.

Comment: Can you link us to an example of this?

Comment: Why are some images in `images/` and others are in `imagens/`?

Comment: @SsJVasto, you are right, I didn't see this error... Working on this for since morning (more than 4 hours)... Thank you!

Comment: @Guybrush How about you leave that Monkey Island and approve my answer?

Comment: @SsJVasto, just in my way :) ... need to wait some minutes to approve an answer, SOF doesn't allow us to approve before this...

Comment: @Guybrush  No problem, nice username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is displaying the "Image not found" image, while IE doesn't show anything.  Your `b.gif` is not in `imagens/`, it is in `images/`

Comment: Holy mother, I am so dumb!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your style to this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {
       font-size: 0; /* there would be no spacing when images are rendered. */
    }
    img.barcode {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block; /* Chrome default is inline */
        vertical-align: top; /* ensure that all images stand at the top. */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a CSS only approach using `flexbox`.

```css
.barcode {
  display: flex;
}
.barcode > div {
  width: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
.barcode .lg {
  width: 3px;
}
.barcode .invert {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="barcode">
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="invert lg"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="invert lg"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="invert lg"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="invert lg"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Every DIV is a bar. Then just define if the bar needs to be *"inverted"* (white) and/or thicker.